# Add text to Layout in code. xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try to add some text to my LinearLayout with a simple condition

```
    var linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLinearLayout);

    if (!myList.Any())
    {
        var t = new TextView(this) { Text = "Empty!" };

        linearLayout.AddView(t);
    }
```

What missing here?

Comment: I'm a Java developer, this may be incorrect. Don't you have to do `t.setText`?

Comment: @LunarWatcher { Text = "Empty!" }; same

Comment: Do you have a listview or any other view inside the linearlayout you want to show the "Empty"?

Comment: @apineda no i dont

Comment: Could you update the post with the content of your .axml file which is the content view of this Activity?

Comment: @apineda    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout">
</LinearLayout>

Comment: your code looks good, makes no sense. try adding LayoutParams to the textView. that's the last thing that comes to my mind and also try without the condition, just to see.

Answer (score 0):

From your `axml` codes, the `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` is wrong, it should be `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. the `http://` part is missing.

Add the missing part and the exception `You must supply a layout_width attribute` will be gone.